# How to add a separator to Gio::Menu

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm

I'm writing an application using GTK3 and gtkmm. I'm adding a menu button to the header bar. So far, I got items to show up, but I can't add a separator.

Here's where I create the menu:

```
auto main_menu = Gio::Menu::create();
```

...and add some items:

```
main_menu->append("Export to WAV", "app.exportToWav");
main_menu->append("About", "app.about");
```

And here's what I get:

[image]

But I want to add a horizontal line between the two items. There seems to be no obvious way to do this with `Gio::Menu`, and I want that popover. I tried adding an item with "-" as its content, but that did nothing. `Gtk::SeparatorMenuItem` exists, but it doesn't seem to be compatible. Is this even doable with this kind of menu?

Comment: Un a minimal and working example would help. I am not familiar with `Gio::Menu` but I could take a look if I don't have to write the base code myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. Turns out, with `Gio::Menu`, you don't specify "separators," per se. Instead, you specify sections.

Essentially, what this means is creating multiple menus, and then grouping them all together in a single menu using the `append_section(Gio::MenuModel)` function.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
// Create master menu
auto main_menu = Gio::Menu::create();

// Create menu sections
auto main_menu_section1 = Gio::Menu::create();
auto main_menu_section2 = Gio::Menu::create();

// Add item(s) to first section
main_menu_section1->append("Export to WAV", "app.exportToWav");

// Add item(s) to second section
main_menu_section2->append("About", "app.about");

// Append the new sections to the master menu
main_menu->append_section(main_menu_section1);
main_menu->append_section(main_menu_section2);
```

Then, each section is separated by a horizontal line:

[image: It's faint, but it's there]
It's faint, but it's there